# How to give border-spacing 0 for a single cell alone?

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="new">21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `border-spacing` for the table is `2px` like this:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 2 2;
}
```

I want the spacing between cell 21 and 22 as `0`.
So I tried :

```
table td.new {
    border-spacing: 0 2;
}
```

But does not work. Any idea please?

Comment: Your CSS is invalid, it should be `border-spacing: 2px 2px;`. But even then I don't think it will work due to the restrictions of the HTML table in general. Maybe merging cells is an option (`colspan="2"`)?

Comment: px is not a problem.. it still works without px.. I don't want to merge the cells.. want to know some work around to achieve without merging..

Comment: border-spacing without px for values >= 0 will not render in Chrome afaik, but well. As pointed out by Hashem in his answer as well, it's not possible. You can only try to build the table with div elements using `display: table-cell;` and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not possible.

`border-spacing` and/or `border-collapse` properties are only applicable to `table`s and `inline-table`s. Therefore you can not override it for specific cells.

If you want to merge those two cells, you could use `colspan`

```css
table{
  border-spacing: 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">21 22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or use nested tables:

```css
body > table {
  border-spacing: 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;;
}

table table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes..I get you.. But I want to know if there is a work around to achieve this without merging cells..

Comment: @ReyRajesh What about nested tables?